# How to create buttons in taskbar menu Windows 7 C#?

Tags: c#, taskbar

How would I make buttons appear in the Windows 7 Taskbar like the image below has it setup?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcH1z.png

[image: Buttons in tasbar]

How would I create buttons in the taskbar with tooltiptext on the button like the picture above?

C# Windows Form.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that some other application already does this, and you're trying to imitate it from C#?  Or is this a novel design that you're trying to implement for the very first time?

Comment: He's trying to utilise a Windows 7 feature, I don't think any clarification is required for that?

Comment: You have asked 17 questions on StackOverflow so far. You have received 38 answers, accepted 2 and up-voted 0. Some of the answers, such as the one about escaping backslashes, have been very good and answered by some very talented people. StackOverflow has been very good to you but you have not shown much appreciation back. Please read the FAQ and consider going through your questions and giving credit where it is due. That is how this site works and thrives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Showing Buttons on taskbar thumbnails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327185/c-sharp-showing-buttons-on-taskbar-thumbnails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), this will give you what you require.

The feature is called 'Thumbnail Toolbar'. There are some icons you can use on your buttons in the [SystemIcons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemicons.aspx) class.

```
ThumbnailToolbarButton infoButton = new ThumbnailToolbarButton(SystemIcons.Information, "Information");
infoButton.Click += delegate {
    // Action
};

TaskbarManager.Instance.ThumbnailToolbars.AddButtons(this.Handle, infoButton);
```