# Is there any way to create user interface, that can show buttons like how windows media player shows it when minimized?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to create windows application in C#.NET, that can show buttons like how windows media player/Lync shows it when minimized and mouse over it?

[image]

I am just curious about how that would be!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842938/how-to-create-buttons-in-taskbar-menu-windows-7-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refer to [ThumbButtonInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.thumbbuttoninfo.aspx) class.

```
        <ThumbButtonInfo x:Name="btnUpdate"
                         ImageSource="{StaticResource IconUpdate}"
                         Description="Find updates for the application"
                         IsBackgroundVisible="True">
        </ThumbButtonInfo>
        <ThumbButtonInfo x:Name="btnClient"
                         ImageSource="{StaticResource IconClient}"
                         Description="Search Clients"
                         IsBackgroundVisible="True">
        </ThumbButtonInfo>
        <ThumbButtonInfo x:Name="btnInvoice"
                         ImageSource="{StaticResource IconInvoice}"
                         Description="Search Invoices"
                         IsBackgroundVisible="True">
        </ThumbButtonInfo>
```