# C# Showing Buttons on taskbar thumbnails

Tags: c#, button, thumbnails, taskbar

In WMP, I have been shown buttons on the taskbar thumbnail. How can I make them for my winforms app in C#?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [WindowsAPICodePack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) contains a control called `ThumbnailToolBarButton` that you can use to get this functionality going.

You'll need to make sure you have icons for each of the buttons (as I don't believe you can put text on them), and then it should be a simple matter of creating new controls and adding relevant event handlers.

Sourced from [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETrGPp17Bss).

Comment: WindowsAPICodePack no longer exists, the link is broken. Try VistaUIFramework, it contains all Windows 7 taskbar features except tabbed thumbnails. https://github.com/myapkapp/VistaUIFramework

Answer (score 5):

XAML

```xaml
<Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <TaskbarItemInfo>
        <TaskbarItemInfo.ThumbButtonInfos>
            <ThumbButtonInfo ImageSource="/IconProgressDemo;component/Icon1.ico" Description="Play!" Click="ThumbButtonInfo_Click" />
            <ThumbButtonInfo ImageSource="/IconProgressDemo;component/Icon2.ico" Description="Stop!" Click="ThumbButtonInfo_Click" />
        </TaskbarItemInfo.ThumbButtonInfos>
    </TaskbarItemInfo>
</Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
```

C#

```cs
private void ThumbButtonInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((sender as System.Windows.Shell.ThumbButtonInfo).Description);
}
```

I haven't tried this hope this will be helpful.

and refer these links.

http://www.zayko.net/post/Adding-Buttons-to-Window-Thumbnail-in-WPF-4-for-Windows-7-(C).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7trainingcourse_win7taskbarmanaged_topic2.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx

and there is Taskbar API available you can try with that.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I have been using winforms.

Comment: I know that I am late, but is there a ref for UWP applications? I cannot use the `System.Windows.Shell` Would like to add media buttons like this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/189ef162-9ca3-41aa-8859-5b8e08c70eaa/taskbar-thumbnail-media-toolbar