# Add buttons to the windows taskbar thumbnail JavaFX?

Tags: windows, javafx

This question has been inactive for over a year now. I still don't have a solution for my problem. I edited this to clarify my problem and bring new attention to it.

If you use Windows you probably know the small preview image (thumbnail) that is shown when you hover the icon of the programm on the taskbar.

Some programms manage (e. g. Spotify, previous versions of Git Extension) to add a button to that popup (where the red line is).

[image: demo image]

For Example: Spotify added some buttons to pause/unpause, skip, etc. I wanted to do something similar for my app.

> The question is if this can be done with JavaFX and how this can be done?

I have searched the internet for a solution but I couldn't find any for JavaFX. For example: here is a solution for [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327185/c-sharp-showing-buttons-on-taskbar-thumbnails).

Comment: You could check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831807/javafx-show-a-pane-on-mouse-hover Although I assume you've found a solution by now.