# Can I set the Windows bar application image?

Tags: windows, javafx

I am currently working on a music app with JavaFX and I have a another question (a bit similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117955/add-components-to-the-windows-bar-javafx)). So you probably know the bar at the bottom of your desktop on Windows. Now an open application will be shown on this bar and when you the button is over it on some versions an small image of the open application will be shown, like this [image: this]

My question is if I can edit this small image to a costum image and how to do it if it is possible. I am using JavaFX!

I imagined something like this:

```
Application.setSubImage(new Image("myImage.png"));
```

Comment: JavaFX itself does not provide an API for this. You may be able to do something through native code.

Comment: @Slaw is correct, but just to affirm - there's currently no Java API *at all* that I'm aware of (swing, awt, swt, desktop api, etc.) that will do this, and I'm also not sure that it's possible to change that image "nicely" even with *native* code - it's designed to pretty consistently be a preview rendering of the application in question. Rendering buttons over it is one thing (such as in the question you linked), but changing it entirely is likely to require rather nasty hacks even on the native level.

Comment: Yes I just wanted the song title image dislpayed in that but it isn't that important as the buttons so I leave it but thanks Slaw and Micheal Berry